# Python match only captures first group

Tags: python, regex, match

I am trying to using python yo match string.

```
>> self._regexs = re.compile("(?P<g0>.*AMD$)|(?P<g1>.*AMD$)|(?P<g2>.*AMD$)|(?P<g3>.*)", re.DEBUG)
>> m = self._regexs.match("AMD")
>> print m.groups()
('AMD', None, None, None)
```

I'd have expected that m.groups() would've displayed:

```
>> print m.groups()
('AMD', 'AMD', 'AMD', None)
```

But apparently I'm doing something wrong. I'd like to know why this solution does not work and how to change it, such that I get the result I'm looking for.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Seems a bit convoluted to me...

Comment: I am using nltk (RegexpTagger) on python. But a word can tag by one tag. I want to change it.

Comment: Might well be worth updating your question with that - possibly mentioning ntlk and your "end goal" rather than the way it is worded now...

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression is acting `greedy` in that it is going to accept the first match. Which in your example is the first capture group, with your particular input. Alternation expressions (signaled by the `|`) will always match the first alternative satisfied by a sample string.

It looks like you're trying to make a `switch` and `case` type of regular expression which cannot be done as it would require backtracking through for each different different sub regular expression between the `|`'s. The result that you wish to achieve is not possible with a single regular expression.

See also:

- [Regular Expression Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)
- [An introduction to regular expression engine internals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html)